# Constant Contact V3 API add new contact

Tags: node.js, constantcontact

I'm attempting to use the new Constant Contact V3 API to add a new email contact. I've been reading the docs: https://v3.developer.constantcontact.com/api_guide/client_flow.html, and trying it out and it seems like the only way to do this now is to make an authentication request, approve the request and then retrieve and access token that is valid for only 2 hours.

I need to have access from my server only and just send an add contact request to Constant Contact. I don't understand why I require to have a redirect uri now and an access token to use the V3 api instead of just using the api key.

With the V2 api I was able to make these types of requests directly from the server without hassle and that's exactly what I need now. The V2 documentation seems to be taken down so I can no longer do that so I'm stuck.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This new trend of these services requiring complex authentication setups for simple API actions is so annoying. I shouldn't have to request and manage an access token just to add an email address to a contact list!

Answer (score 1):

Based on this link: https://community.constantcontact.com/t5/Developer-Support-ask-questions/v2-or-v3-API-for-very-basic-integration/m-p/324777#M11434, it seems like server-to-server auth is not available still. For those of you who have the same issue, use Mail Chimp or another service that has basic api requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You can get **INITIAL** Access Token without any code - just use your browser and `curl`. The Access Token is valid for 24 h, but you can automatically renew it using Refresh Token. You can renew it automatically every time it expires and never need to proceed through INITIAL flow over again. You can read about it [here](https://developer.constantcontact.com/api_guide/server_flow.html). If you are using C#, I have templates and instructions exactly for your scenario here: https://github.com/mikeks/constantcontact-v3.